# How to generate a bit string that loops?

Tags: algorithm, haskell

Mind the following code:

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) (Tree a) | Leaf a deriving Show

foldTree node leaf tree = go tree where
    go (Node a b) = node (go a) (go b)
    go (Leaf x)   = leaf x

toList :: Tree a -> [a] 
toList = foldTree (++) (\a->[a])

genTree a b c d e = iterate grow base where
    base          = e
    grow tree     = Node left right where
        left      = foldTree a c tree
        right     = foldTree b d tree

bins, grays :: [Tree String]
bins  = genTree Node Node        (Leaf.('0':)) (Leaf.('1':)) (Leaf [])
grays = genTree Node (flip Node) (Leaf.('0':)) (Leaf.('1':)) (Leaf [])

main = mapM 
    (\ (a, b) -> putStrLn (a ++ " " ++ b)) 
    (zip (toList (bins !! 3)) (toList (grays !! 3)))
```

This program outputs the following:

```
000 000
001 001
010 011
011 010
100 110
101 111
110 101
111 100
```

Now, lets do the following experiment: we go to a random line, print the string on the left, go to the line starting with the string on the right, repeat. If we start on line `100 110`, we will print the following: `100, 110, 101, 111, 100, 110, 101, 111, 100 ...`. This repeats the same 4 numbers infinitely. If we started on the first line, we would just print `000` forever. **My question is: can we replace `grays` with a function such that, when doing the experiment above, we always loops through all lines?**

Comment: What would the type of the new `grays` function (call it `grays'`) be? If it's still `grays' :: [Tree String]`, I don't think it's possible. I don't think it's possible to construct a `t :: Tree` such that `toList t` generates the infinite sequence that you expect.

Comment: It is, the `Tree` is just an awkward format for the table above. One of such tables would be `000 001; 001 010; 010 011; 011 100; ...`. This table satisfies the req because the sequence is `000 -> 001 -> 010 ... 000 ...`. All 8 numbers are there. The problem is, how do you generate that table with a non-accumulating fold?

Comment: Surely all folds are accumulating folds?

Comment: Why not use a simpler representation, like just a function? For example, you can write the infinite loop which visits each element in sequence as `loop0 ~(r0:r1:r2:r3:_) = [ r1, r2, r3, r0 ]`. "Running" this is quite simple (require RankNTypes): `printLoop :: (forall t . [t] -> [t]) -> [String] -> IO (); printLoop l = fix (\pr i xs -> putStrLn (xs !! i) >> pr (l [0..] !! 0) (l xs)) 0`.